# SOS_Scheduler_Yield wait type

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a process that has a last_wait_type as SOS_Scheduler_Yield. It is inserting 100 records to a table. This process has been with this wait type forever with low CPU utilization %.

There are other processes executing the same query simultaneously without this wait type and executing in minutes. What could be the reason for this process hanging? It has been in runnable state with Last_wait_type as SOS_Scheduler_Yield for that long.

Comment: Have you checked power management setting to see if it is set to high performance mode ? Also, check [**this**](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/sql-performance/knee-jerk-waits-sos-scheduler-yield) blog post from Paul Randal on how to go about troubleshooting `SOS_Scheduler_Yield`

Comment: Quick Question, is that particular process still running where it's trying to insert into the table or is it just the recorded wait stats post action?  I am assuming it is the wait stats after it finished, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The simple occurrence of `SOS_Scheduler_Yield` don't mean very much. This can have some other causes.

Generally you can take a look at this `DMV` to clarify some things.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats 
WHERE wait_type = 'SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD'
```

**Interpretation** of `dm_os_wait_stats`:

- *High* counter values, *low* time means everything ok. This mainly just means that there are many queries which run in parallel and need to be scheduled to different threads.
- *High* counter values, *high* time can cause some problems. **Beware** you many intensive queries which may take long time to run (e.g. Aggregation on big tables).
- *Low* counter values, *high* time can indicate some intensive queries which take very long to complete. **Beware** this may be a CPU bottle neck which may be through bigger data loads or poor design (e.g. user defined functions).

Another good resource to look at may be the schedulers itself:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers
WHERE scheduler_id < 255
ORDER BY scheduler_id
```

It will provide you the status of each CPU. Basically description of this statement:

- **parent_node_id** represents the `NUMA` node of the core.
- **scheduler_id** and **cpu_id** are basically in many cases the same. They represent the CPU number.
- **status** will represent if the CPU is used for processing steps in the SQL Server instance (`affinity_mask`)
- **is_idle** represents the state of the cpu. 1 = it does nothing/not much and 0 = on load!
- ***_switches_count** represent the value of the switches between some states. High `context_switches_count` tends to show that the CPU cycles between different operations while `idle_switches_count` indicates if the CPU goes often idle and back to work or not. Generally low `idle_switches_count` indicates that your system is under permanent pressure.
- **current_tasks_count** shows how many tasks were assigned to this cpu.
- **runnable_tasks_count** shows how many tasks *really* run on the corresponding cpu.
- **load_factor** shows the pressure on this single core.

Hopefully this will clarify things for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote the article about this and maybe someone can find it useful.

[How to handle excessive SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait type values in SQL Server](http://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-handle-excessive-sos_scheduler_yield-wait-type-values-in-sql-server/)

I tried to provide not only multiple aspects of troubleshooting SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait type but also to give some details on SQL OS Scheduler functionality, as it is crucial for understanding SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits

Answer (score 0):

Without having high CPU utilization you can probably just ignore it but watch it when utilization goes high.  This most likely means that 'your CPU is under sustained pressure and threads are being scheduled as normal'.  SQL OS manages threads in the MS SQL Server app, not Windows OS.  SQL OS uses a method where threads are released by the process on purpose so that a single thread doesn't get too greedy and start starving other actions.  Your scheduler is a representative of that process.

Here is some more back ground:

http://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/sql-performance/knee-jerk-waits-sos-scheduler-yield

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joesack/should-you-worry-about-sos_scheduler_yield)